# I need help with divergence and gradient?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, physics, partial-derivative

$$A_z = \mu{\frac{e^{-jBr}}{4\pi r}}∫I(z')e^{jBz'\cos\theta}dz'$$

Midway into my question, I want to compute:

$$-j\left( \frac{\nabla(\nabla\cdot A) }{w\mu\varepsilon} \right).$$

Symbols like $ w, \mu, \varepsilon, B $ are basically constants for things like frequency, permittivity, permeability and $r$ is just radius.

The result would be something like $ A_z \cos\theta \hat r$. I don't really know how to go about doing a divergence on this, and then a gradient. I did calc3 about 4 years ago, and between I have forgotten a lot. I need help at this step, if anyone needed the full problem, just comment.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking for. Can you post the full problem statement?